# How to use key of MAP in Criteria Query?

Tags: hibernate, criteria-api, hibernate-criteria

I have a Bean like this

```
Class TestA
{
    Map<String,TestB> testBMap;
}

Class TestB
{
    String data;
    ...
}
```

I want to fetch  the `TestA` data along with the map `testBMap` where `key ='test1'`.

How can i do this using Hibernate.

Answer (score 4):

The key must be the value of one of the persistent fields of TestB (let's says this field is names "foo"), so this code should work :

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(TestA.class, "a");
criteria.createAlias("a.testBMap", "b");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("b.foo", "test1"));
criteria.setFetchMode("a.testBMap", FetchMode.JOIN);
return criteria.list();
```

Comment: I think this gives the exception: 'org.hibernate.MappingException: collection was not an association'

Comment: I get "Illegal Syntax near Collection"

Answer (score 3):

In my case this did work fine:

```
countries = getSession().createCriteria( Country.class ).add( Restrictions.in( "region", regions ) )
                .createAlias( "name.translations", "translation" )
                .add( Restrictions.eq( "translation.indices", 'en' )).list();
```

The mapping is like this:
Country has property name which is of type LocalizedText (an entity)
`LocalizedText` contains `Map<String, String>` translations where key is language code and value is country name that corresponds to that language.
So i had to create alias for translations and then user "magic" postfix ".indices" in `eq()`.

Comment: Wow. This is magic indeed. Where did you got the ".indices" trick for referencing the map key?

Comment: I guess it's best to write `eq("translation." + CollectionPropertyNames.COLLECTION_INDICES)` instead.

Comment: @Laurent, i had to dig into the source code, but yes using the constant makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Until Hibernate implements JPA's `key()` function (see [HHH-5396](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5396)), you can use the `index()` function:

```java
session
    .createQuery("select a from TestA a join a.testBMap m where index(m) = :key")
    .setParameter("key", "test1")
    .list();
```

Comment: What is the Criteria equivalent for this? I am interested in the context of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043996/use-hibernate-criteria-for-filtering-keys-and-values-in-map

Comment: Thanks a lot boss.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(TestA.class);
criteria.createAlias("testBMap", "t");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("t." + CollectionPropertyNames.COLLECTION_INDEX, "test1"));
return criteria.list();
```